# WebApi file download via handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WebAPI for downloading a .pdf file like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile(string id, bool attachment = true)
{
HttpResponseMessage result = null;

try
{
    MyService service = new MyService();
    var bytes = await service.DownloadFileAsync(id);

    if (bytes != null)
    {
        result = GetBinaryFile(personalDocument, string.Format("{0}.pdf", id), attachment);
    }
    else
    {
        result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { ReasonPhrase = "ServerError" });
}

return result;
}
private HttpResponseMessage GetBinaryFile(byte[] bytes, string fileName, bool attachment)
{
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   // result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
result.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes));
//result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");

if (attachment)
{
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
}

result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
return result;
}
```

now, i see that it frozen my site, so i want to change that, and download a pdf file via handler, it's possible to route to IHttpHandler with any changes by client side? by Route attribute?

Comment: May be make GetBinaryFile() method async as well

Comment: GetBinaryFile is just wrapper the file with HttpResponseMessage and return the result.

Comment: getbinaryfile is what freezing your site. you need to able to call await on that

Comment: i make that as async method, the issue is remains..

Comment: Does it hang on all browsers? I currently trying to figure out a a similar issue when i realized that the PDF is downloading fine on all other browsers except IE11

Comment: i check that on chrome, about ie11it seems that angular isn't plays good with ie11:/. for now i implement IHttpAsyncHandler, and now everythings are good:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the article that from http://www.fsmpi.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/task-based-ihttpasynchandler/532.html is helps me to implement the async handler.

and by web.config it possible to route to places:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
  <handlers>  
    <add
       name="DownFile"
       path="/api/downloads/MyDownload.axd"
       type="MyProject.WebApi.Handlers.MyDownloadAsyncHandler, MyProject.WebApi"
       verb="GET"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question rigth, you try to send some content from server to user. If so, try to use `PushStreamContent` type and, actually you do not need to have specific handler for this.

Example of `PushStreamContent` with sending zip file

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()

// Do something with 'zip'

var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
{
    zip.Save(stream);
    stream.Close();
}, "application/zip");

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = pushStreamContent,
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
};

response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "fileName"
};

response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");

return response;
```

Comment: i cannot, because i already did some like that, but always for the first time it frozen my site, so i use handler for that.

Comment: actually, i should not froze your site. maybe you have some ither handlers or logic, which is running too slow? also, if you don't use async controllers methods, try to use - it also should remove all frozen states

Comment: i working with web api, and angular site, and as you can to see, all the mehtods are async:) but it seems that if i download a file and set attachment to be true, it frozen, so i working with handler, and the problem is resolved for me:)

Comment: sorry, missed async :). ok, if it solves your problem)